# Send a text message on Instagram app using URI

Tags: instagram

WhatsApp allows users to send a message using URI with the format `whatsapp://send?text=<message>`.

Is there a similar way to send messages on the Instagram app?

Comment: The Android instagram listens for the scheme `instagram://` as "host name" (instead of `send` as it is on whatsapp) it accepts commands like `create_post`, `create_messenger_room`, `android` and a lot more (see AndroidManifest.xml of Instagram app. I don't use this app and I have not tried it what other parameters are required but trying it out and checking `adb logcat` for errors might help you to identify how to use this interface.

Comment: does every app listens for the scheme which stats with the ```app_name://``` as hostname

Comment: An app listens for a scheme if it has been declared in it's AndroidManifest.xml. Some apps do, others not.